# XML to XSD to .NET class object and accessing the object

Tags: c#, xml, rest

My overall goal is to be able return an XML response from my REST API to .NET clients. Before I do that, I need to understand how to classify this data, such that the clients can understand it. I plan on deserializing XML into a class object. I am using an example of Cars at the moment.

I have the following XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<CarCollection>
<Cars>
  <Car>
    <StockNumber>1020</StockNumber>
    <Make>Nissan</Make>
    <Model>Sentra</Model>
  </Car>
  <Car>
    <StockNumber>1010</StockNumber>
    <Make>Toyota</Make>
    <Model>Corolla</Model>
  </Car>
  <Car>
    <StockNumber>1111</StockNumber>
    <Make>Honda</Make>
    <Model>Accord</Model>
  </Car>
</Cars>
</CarCollection>
```

I generated the following XSD via the XSD.exe tool (using the xml file above):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema id="CarCollection" xmlns="" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata">
  <xs:element name="CarCollection" msdata:IsDataSet="true" msdata:UseCurrentLocale="true">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
        <xs:element name="Cars">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="Car" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                <xs:complexType>
                  <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="StockNumber" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                    <xs:element name="Make" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                    <xs:element name="Model" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                  </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
              </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:choice>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

By which, I generated the following C# class (command: xsd.exe carcollection.xsd /c):

```
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// <auto-generated>
//     This code was generated by a tool.
//     Runtime Version:4.0.30319.42000
//
//     Changes to this file may cause incorrect behavior and will be lost if
//     the code is regenerated.
// </auto-generated>
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

using System.Xml.Serialization;

// 
// This source code was auto-generated by xsd, Version=4.6.1586.0.
// 


/// <remarks/>
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "4.6.1586.0")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType=true)]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace="", IsNullable=false)]
public partial class CarCollection {

    private CarCollectionCars[] itemsField;

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("Cars", Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
    public CarCollectionCars[] Items {
        get {
            return this.itemsField;
        }
        set {
            this.itemsField = value;
        }
    }
}

/// <remarks/>
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "4.6.1586.0")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType=true)]
public partial class CarCollectionCars {

    private CarCollectionCarsCar[] carField;

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("Car", Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
    public CarCollectionCarsCar[] Car {
        get {
            return this.carField;
        }
        set {
            this.carField = value;
        }
    }
}

/// <remarks/>
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "4.6.1586.0")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType=true)]
public partial class CarCollectionCarsCar {

    private string stockNumberField;

    private string makeField;

    private string modelField;

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
    public string StockNumber {
        get {
            return this.stockNumberField;
        }
        set {
            this.stockNumberField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
    public string Make {
        get {
            return this.makeField;
        }
        set {
            this.makeField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
    public string Model {
        get {
            return this.modelField;
        }
        set {
            this.modelField = value;
        }
    }
}
```

I added the XML file and XSD above to my project. Here is my main class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Xml;

namespace xmlToClass
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(CarCollection));
            CarCollection collection;

            var dir = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
            var file = dir + @"\test.xml";

            using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(file))
            {
                collection = (CarCollection)ser.Deserialize(reader);
            }

            //I can access these directly
            Console.WriteLine(collection.Car[0].StockNumber);
            Console.WriteLine(collection.Car[1].StockNumber);
            Console.WriteLine(collection.Car[2].StockNumber);

            //TODO: How to iterate over this collection?

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

**I want to be able to iterate over this collection as well as access the properties at the same time.** I've tried a foreach loop, but the console only printed the namespace and the object name "xmlToClass.CarCollection+CarsRow" (the default toString() method).

```
    foreach(var car in con.Cars)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(car);
    }
```

I would use a for loop, but I cannot get the length of the collection. I suppose I do not understand the generated class properties or fields... I would SUPER appreciate some direction! Bonus question(s) (after I understand how to properly accessing these objects that are XML deserialized to classes):

1. What if I wanted to StockNumber to be of type "int" or "integer" INSTEAD of string? I've tried adding a type attribute to the XML document and regenerating the XSD to no avail.

Thank you for your time! If you want the project files, I can send them to you.

### Notes

1. I don't want to edit the XSD or .CS file directly, since both are generated from an XML document. Any changes that need to be made to the XML document will warrant a re-generation of the XSD/CS files.

Answer (score 0):

> "I've tried a foreach loop, but the console only printed the namespace
>   and the object name "xmlToClass.CarCollection+CarsRow":"

Your for each is working, the issue is you are seeing the default implementation of ToString().  If you implement your own you can control the output - e.g.

```
public override string ToString()
{
  return $"stock:{stockNumberField} make: {makeField}";
}
```

> What if I wanted to StockNumber to be of type "int" or "integer"
>   INSTEAD of string?

Then change the declaration and regenerate your classes

```
<xs:element name="StockNumber" type="xs:int" minOccurs="0" />
```

Comment: Both the class and the XSD are generated automatically. So if I make changes to the original XML, the custom toString()  method, and the data type in the XSD, will be removed. I'll update my question. I'm looking for ways to access properties outside of the class, as well as setting data types in the original XML such that the XSD.exe tool can interpret them and store them in the XML Schema Definition.

Comment: The whole reason xsd builds partial classes is so you can implement things like ToString() in a seperate code file (same class - partial of course) which isn't affected by the regeneration.

Comment: There are a bunch of questions around why xsd generates strings instead of int, etc.  Presuming you are generating from xml to xsd to code, then there is no easy answer for that - it seems to be a limitation of the tool.  You could always expose a property as an int in another partial class which does the conversion for end users...or start with a schema first approach instead of starting from the xml.

Comment: I see. Thanks for the very important note on partial classes--not something I've dived into with C# yet. As for the XSD data typing, thanks for the insight. I'm going to let this question sit around for a couple days before I mark an answer. I really appreciate your time!